# Dots in printf in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I encountered this snippet but couldn't understand how it works, especially the `printf` statements. Can someone explain

```
void remove_trailing_zeroes()
{
    int a,b; 
    bool f1,f2;
    f1=a%2;
    f2=b%2;
    if (f1==f2) {
        printf("%.0lf\n",(a*1.+b)/2.);
    }
    else {
        printf("%.1lf\n",(a*1.+b)/2.);
    }

}
```

EDIT: I have rephrased my question, help me improve it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Couldn't understand how what works?  You didn't identify the line in question. Did you write this yourself, or is it someone elses code?

Comment: To start with, there are uninitialized values, so it´s just wrong.

Comment: That particular piece of code is undefined since it uses uninitialised variables, so it doesn't work at all. You need a more reliable snippet source.

Comment: `EDIT: I have rephrased my question` But the code is wrong nonetheless. And what´s exactly unclear about the printf lines? ... Maybe you should say what you want to achieve instead of posting nonsensical wrong code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are puzzled about the dots here is what they are:

- `%.1lf` is the format specification for precision. This is requesting one digit after the decimal point in the `printf` output.
- The `1.` and `2.` in `(a*1.+b)/2.` mean that those literals are `double` (as opposed to `1` that would be `int` and `1.f` that would be `float`). Whoever wrote that snippet was probably trying to avoid truncation in computing that average (given `a` and `b` are `int`).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like:

```
printf("%g", (a+b)/2.);
```

emulation.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it prints average value between `a` and `b`.

This if decides when the result will need decimal point `.5`:

```
bool f1,f2;
f1=a%2;
f2=b%2;
if (f1==f2)
```

It would be better to just write:

```
// get a and b from somewhere
if ((a+b)%2) // check if sum can be divided by 2
    printf("%.1lf\n",(a+b)/2.); // %.1lf will print value with 1 decimal ("xX.X")
else
    printf("%.0lf\n",(a+b)/2.); // %.0lf will print value without decimals ("xX")
```